# Duplicating Cell Text Formating using Offset/Indirect

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to create a "GUI" for my sheet with variable inputs options depending on other inputs. This means I have to summon the text from elsewhere using `Offset()` or `Indirect()` or similar functions. However, whenever I use those functions, all text formatting like **bolding** or subscripts are removed.

Example:

A1: "V<sub>∞,final</sub>"

A2: `=indirect(A1)` → "V∞,final"

Are there any functions or options in Excel for those sorts of formatting options to be carried over?

Comment: As in, in-cell text formatting? I don't think so. `CELL` doesn't understand formatting at that level of granularity. You could use VBA which can execute the format painter, as long as the formatting is applied to the entire cell. Or you could use VBA to copy the cell contents entirely, which is the only way I can think of to preserve formatting that's applied selectively within a single cell, as in your example.

Comment: Differential character formatting within a cell can only be applied to text strings. It cannot be done to the results of formulas.  If you did your "lookup" using a VBA sub (not a function), you could probably do that with a copy/paste operation.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the `GUI code` you have tried so far, will help us to understand your need to fix it . Also you need to modify Title of the question since it contradicts with you need, `all text formatting like bold or subscripts are removed.`